# Why is liquibase unable to connect on a Spring Boot app running in bootRun with Docker Compose?

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, liquibase

I have a non-trivial app that I want to incorporate liquibase, r2dbc and mysql.  But when I tried to add what I think is minimal I get the following problem.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'172.22.0.1' (using password: YES)

I'm using Docker Compose support so `compose.yml` looks like this which is basically the one in the Spring Initializr

```yaml
services:
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase'
      - 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret'
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret'
      - 'MYSQL_USER=myuser'
    ports:
      - '3306'
```

I tried to create an MVCE using [Spring Initialzr docker-compose,mysql,data-r2dbc,liquibase,webflux](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.1.3&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=liquibaseplusr2dbc&name=liquibaseplusr2dbc&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.liquibaseplusr2dbc&dependencies=docker-compose,mysql,data-r2dbc,liquibase,webflux) with `db.changelog-master.yaml` as

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: id
      author: author
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: aTable
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: INT
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
              - column:
                  name: value 
                  type: varchar(200)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
```

But I am unable to recreate the issue and the logs appear to work correctly connecting to the composed mysql

> Connected to myuser@172.23.0.1@jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:54863/mydatabase

Comment: What is 172.22.0.1? Is this IP *visible* to the container you're running your spring App in? It's difficult to assist unless you share the `networks` configuration section of your `docker-compose.yml`. Most likely, though, you should be using service names (like `mysql:3306`) as handles to other containers

Comment: Also, how are `myuser` access permissions configured? With MySQL, make sure to use the `GRANT CONNECT ON ... TO 'myuser'@'%'` syntax

Comment: I am trying to find out how to "debug" the boot run since it will stop the database after before I can connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that because `mysql` had a VOLUME defined (I totally forgot about it).  I had to delete the volume associated with it.

To be more precise I had to do the following

```
docker compose rm -fsv # delete the container and volume associations
docker volume prune -f # delete the actual volume
```

The second one was the missing step I had forgotten.  What happens is when I restart the compose it reattaches to that volume where I had a different user ID and password initially.